# Is it possible to make change the node size according to a list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I made a graph. Here I am using a single value for node size. I want to change the node size according to the `size_of_node` list.

***Code:***

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx 
from netgraph import Graph 

triangle = nx.DiGraph([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a')])
size_of_node = [3,1, 4]
edge_labels = {
    ('a', 'b') : 3,
    ('a', 'c') : 10,
    ('b', 'a') : 4
}

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(14,14))

Graph(triangle, node_labels=True, edge_labels=edge_labels,
      edge_label_fontdict=dict(size=12, fontweight='bold'),
      edge_layout='curved',
      node_size=3, edge_width=4, arrows=True, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

How can I change node size according to a list?

Comment: What were your attempts so far?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can pass a dictionary (instead of a list) with the node sizes that you want to the `node_size` argument of the function.
The code looks like that:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx 
from netgraph import Graph 

triangle = nx.DiGraph([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a')])
size_of_node_dict = {'a':3,'b':1, 'c':4}
edge_labels = {
    ('a', 'b') : 3,
    ('a', 'c') : 10,
    ('b', 'a') : 4
}

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(14,14))

Graph(triangle, node_labels=True, edge_labels=edge_labels,
      edge_label_fontdict=dict(size=12, fontweight='bold'),
      edge_layout='curved',    
      node_label_fontdict=dict(size=20), 
      node_size=size_of_node_dict, edge_width=4, arrows=True, ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

The output looks like that:

[image]